# Spark Performance issue while adding more worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am being new on Spark. I am facing performance issue when the number of worker nodes are increased. So to investigate that, I have tried some sample code on spark-shell.

I have created a Amazon AWS EMR with 2 worker nodes (m3.xlarge). I have used the following code on spark-shell on the master node.

```
var df = sqlContext.range(0,6000000000L).withColumn("col1",rand(10)).withColumn("col2",rand(20))
df.selectExpr("id","col1","col2","if(id%2=0,1,0) as key").groupBy("key").agg(avg("col1"),avg("col2")).show()
```

This code executed without any issues and took around 8 mins. But when I have added 2 more worker nodes (m3.xlarge) and executed the same code using spark-shell on master node, the time increased to 10 mins.

Here is the issue, I think the time should be decreased, not by half, but I should decrease. I have no idea why on increasing worker node same spark job is taking more time. Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Are you running on YARN or standalone mode?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I am using YARN

Comment: Have you set `yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator` in capacity-scheduler.xml? Otherwise YARN will only use two executors no matter what you specify with the `--num-executors` flag. That could explain why you get roughly the same execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@z-star, yes an algorithm might b slow when distributed. I found the solution by using [Spark Dynamic Allocation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation). This enable spark to use only required executors. While the static allocation runs a job on all executors, which was increasing the execution time with more nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, but it is possible for an algorithm to run slower when distributed. 
Basically, if the synchronization part is a heavy one, doing that with 2 nodes will take more time then with one.
I would start by comparing some simpler transformations, running a more asynchronous code, as without any sync points (such as group by key), and see if you get the same issue.